# Sync Framework: Can you sync over http

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

We are planning to use Sync Services for ADO.NET to sync stores with headoffice and it has been suggested that I sync via a **WCF proxy**.

Does syncing via a WCF proxy mean that I will be able to **sync over http**? If not, is it possible to use sync services to sync via http.

(I do not want to update our **firewall** every time we get a new store that needs to sync with the headoffice -- that is why I want to sync via http).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, WCF implments both SOAP and REST webservices, either can which can be exposed over http or http/s.

[Here's some documentation from MSDN on WCF.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx)

We always use http/s (SSL), even inside our LAN.